# UIPopoverController alternative both for iPad and iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, uipopover

I want to have some universal ui component which I can use for both iPad and iPhone. Since popovers are available only for iPad I want to have a single component which will run on both devices. I don't want to have to write separate modules since this is not a major feature anyways. What I need is to present a web view in some sort of popup which does not cover the whole screen. Is there a component in the framework I can use?
I need to run it on iOS 6 and 7.

Comment: Look up a component on GitHub or Cocoa Controls

Comment: No you will not find that kind of controller in iOS SDK. You have to go for open source or create your own. One suggestion from my side is : https://github.com/nicolaschengdev/WYPopoverController

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

FPPopover provides an alternative to the native iOS UIPopoverController, adding support for iPhone and additional opportunities to customize the look and feel of the popovers.

https://github.com/50pixels/FPPopover